# Sqlalchemy trusted connection not working

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Using sqlalchemy in python3, I am attempting to connect to a MS Sql Server 2016 database. Here is the command:

```
engine = sql.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@localhost/dbname?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
```

Attempting any transaction after this, such as:

```
engine.execute(text('DELETE FROM tablename').execution_options(autocommit = True))
```

produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2339, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 364, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 778, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 495, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 140, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 137, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 309, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 440, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 661, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 656, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\python-ratings\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 493, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default dri
ver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong? The user I am logged in as can connect to the db with Windows Authentication.

Comment: Try omitting the `trusted_connection=yes&` from your connection URI. I've never needed to use it.

Comment: Could you post your connection string please? I tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: I just use `mssql+pyodbc://@localhost:49242/mydb?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server`

Comment: False alarm. Was trying to use an odbc driver that was not installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was trying to use an ms odbc driver version that wasn't installed on the machine. All good now.